# UEFI Ubuntu installation no longer boots after moving a partition

Tags: boot, partitioning, uefi, mbr, gpt

After <strike>resizing</strike> moving a large partition on the same drive with Gparted that contains my EFI partition, my Ubuntu installation (15.04 x64) no longer boots in EFI mode. When I try to manually load the boot option corresponding to Ubuntu in the Bios boot menu, nothing happens (the screen blinks and returns me to the menu). The machine is a Dell Optiplex, and when I try to "Add Boot Option" I get a message saying "File System Not Found!". I've checked with a bootable Ubuntu USB that all my partitions do still exist and are accessible though.

I've tried repairing the EFI partition with the boot-repair tool but no luck. I'm not sure what else I can do. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have more than 1 distro installed? Do you have Win8 installed?

Comment: Ah right yes, so the actual operations gparted would have done would be a move to the left and then grow etc.

Comment: A move to left will definitely cause this since the boot files can no longer be found. This should be easily fixed by reinstalling grub2 from the live distro and then running update-grub. There's several answers that explain this.

Comment: Oh wait I have the pastebin output from the boot-repair tool: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10987743/

Comment: @chaskes Even though the EFI partition is at the start of the disk?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23447/discussion-between-chaskes-and-humble-coffee).

Comment: Your sda1 is the ESP or efi system partition which must be FAT32. But partition table says Linux formated type 83 even though header still says FAT32. UUID also says FAT32. So change partition table type, not reformat back to FAT32.  Use Disks  Edit partition (gear icon) to change to EFI System Partition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your installation is very strange:

- Your partition table is MBR, which almost always indicates a BIOS-mode boot. In the case of Windows, MBR *requires* a BIOS-mode boot.
- You've got the Windows boot loader installed in the MBR.
- Your first partition has a FAT filesystem and contains EFI boot loaders, apparently for both Linux and Windows (although the Windows files might actually be copies of GRUB created by Boot Repair). Note that EFI is not BIOS, so there's an inconsistency with the first two points.
- Your first partition's type code is 0x83, which is normally used only by Linux. Its contents imply that it's an EFI System Partition (ESP), though. An MBR ESP should have a type code of 0xEF.
- You have no obvious NTFS partitions, so if there's a Windows installation involved, it's not clear where it is. The presence of both BIOS and EFI Windows boot loaders is therefore puzzling, although perhaps explicable.

If I had to guess, I'd say you had a Windows installation, but you installed Ubuntu over it, and that you either converted from a BIOS-mode boot to boot in EFI mode or you installed in EFI mode and then changed the partition table from GPT to MBR.

For recovery, my first advice is to proceed cautiously. Your installation is strange enough that you could easily make matters worse if you start making random changes. When you make changes, begin with changes you can easily undo. Part of proceeding cautiously is to use an emergency boot disc to back up any important personal data from your disk. A mistake or unidentified problem could easily result in actual data loss, so you should be prepared for that with a backup.

One cautious way to proceed is to try using the USB flash drive or CD-R version of my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) to see if it will boot your system. It *should* boot it, assuming the OS itself is in order. If rEFInd can boot your OS, then you can proceed to make adjustments to your partition table (described shortly). If not, then you should start investigating the possibility of filesystem corruption or accidentally-damaged files. Reporting the details of what shows up in the rEFInd menu, and what happens when you select each option, may be helpful in providing further advice in this case.

If rEFInd can boot Ubuntu, I'd start by changing the type code of `/dev/sda1` from 0x83 to 0xEF. You can do this in `fdisk` by using the `t` option. You might then be able to get it to boot by adjusting items in your firmware, by re-installing GRUB (`grub-install`), or by installing rEFInd to your hard disk. It's at least as likely, though, that you'll need to convert your MBR disk to GPT form. You can do this with `gdisk`; see [here](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html) for detailed instructions. This conversion is reversible, but not as easily as a change to the first partition's type code, so I'd start with that simple step first. After converting from MBR to GPT, you'll almost certainly have to setup or re-install GRUB or install rEFInd to your hard disk to get the system booting.

Comment: You're analysis was spot on. The solution was 1) converting MBR to GPT then 2) reinstalling GRUB. Just re-installing GRUB was insufficient on it's own. And yes, clobbering the Windows installation on this work machine was the first thing I did after getting it. Thanks ever so much for your help :)